# How does someone access an encrypted OSX folder from Linux?

Tags: linux, macos, encryption, file-transfer

How does someone access an encrypted OSX folder from Linux?  I've mounted the OSX drive on Linux however some folders are not readable.

Comment: Are they encrypted or are they just not readable because your Linux user doesn't have permission?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is such a thing as "encrypted OS X folders". HFS+ does not support that.

It's all disk images (`.dmg`, `.sparseimage`, `.sparsebundle`, etc.) that are mounted using `hdiutil` in OS X.

Simple, unencrypted `.dmgs` can be mounted, anything else (sparse/FileVault images, encrypted disk images) can't.

If you're a developer, you might be able to adapt [VileFault](http://code.google.com/p/vilefault/) (also see [here](http://crypto.nsa.org/vilefault/)) to your needs -- I'm afraid that's the closest you get to a tool for that. And I don't think they support sparsebundles/-images either.

Comment: From what I understand you can access OSX files from Linux by changing the User ID on the Linux system.

Comment: @vsh3r This has nothing to do with encryption. These are [file system permissions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filesystem_permissions).